# rcp targets: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When I am trying to debug my RCP application using targets it is prompting to the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at com.cerner.genesis.application.library.warden.WardenApplicationLibrary.getPublishedApplicationsForRole(WardenApplicationLibrary.groovy:306)
```

I want to know how to troubleshoot this? It looks like eclipse configuration issue to me.

Comment: Please, include code and more details. Without seeing what you have tried we can't help you. Consider including a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

You try to call 'isEmpty' method on null object, maybe you haven't declared or initialized this object before.
Need to see you code

Comment: This error comes from node module. It's probably a versioning error